# UITableView Section Headers not visible when table in visible rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, drawrect

I have a `UIScrollView` with 3 `UITableViews` stacked horizontally. I switch between these tableviews using a tab-controller on top. However, when I switch to the 2nd or 3rd tab and switch back quickly to 1st the `section headers` don't show. They display when I scroll the `tableView`. These are `custom headers` (jfyi). I tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` when the tableView is visible, but that does not help because as per Apple Docs :

> If you simply change the geometry of the view, the view is typically not redrawn. Instead, its existing content is adjusted based on the value in the view’s contentMode property. Redisplaying the existing content improves performance by avoiding the need to redraw content that has not changed.

Since, only the geometry of the view is changing here, it does not help. Also this happens on all versions `iOS 5~6.1` and on simulator and device. Thankfully, this does not crash the app, but its a problem nevertheless. Could someone help? I am attaching pictures for reference. First shows the problem, second: after scrolling the "head(er)less" tableview

[image: Headless TableView sections][image: We have a Head. Ta-da !!]

**EDIT**: 
I am using simple `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` to switch between tableviews. This does the trick but I just observed that when I set `...animated:NO` all is okay. The problem happens when `...animated:YES`

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the switching code, where probably the problem lies.

Comment: Try to use a `UIPageViewController` instead of a scroll view.

Comment: I am sorry, but that is not very helpful. UIPageViewController might be powerful but a simple UIScrollView is very useful for just scrolling actions.

Comment: I successfully use a `UIPageViewController` in a quite similar situation. The difference would be that each TableView/Page would have its own controller. This means that you would encapsulate responsibility for the drawing of your views and your problems most probably would disappear. To decide whether this hint is helpful or not to **you** is of course **your** personal decision.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue of displaying and scrolling taking place simultaneously for the respective tableview. So what you can do here is:

1. Remove the scroll animation
   or
2. Just scroll the tableview to top on the tab press event
   or
3. simply reload the tableView which is made visible